# Cannot detect two views overlay

Tags: android, animation

I have written a small 2D animation app where the user moves around an ImageView  in the layout with DPAD directions. There is another ImageView which serves as goal. If the ball gets inside the goal, a success message should be displayed. The code below is wrong in the sense that as soon as one moves the DPAD, the success message is displayed!

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    ObjectAnimator animator;
    switch(keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
            animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball, "translationX", ball.getX() + STEP_X);
                    animator.start();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball, "translationX", ball.getX() - STEP_X);
            animator.start();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
            animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball, "translationY", ball.getY() - STEP_Y);
            animator.start();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
            animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball, "translationY",   ball.getY() + STEP_Y);
        animator.start();
        break;
    }
    Rect ballRect = new Rect(ball.getLeft(), ball.getTop(), ball.getRight(), ball.getBottom());
    Rect goalRect = new Rect(goal.getLeft(), goal.getTop(), goal.getRight(), ball.getBottom());

    if(goalRect.intersect(ballRect)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Goal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/goal"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/field" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/object"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="Object"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ball" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Preview:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: can you give more about image views that you are using

Comment: Sure @ramanavv! added

Comment: @JasonStack did you get a chance to see if my answer helped?

Answer (score 1):

The below code will be worked for you:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    ObjectAnimator animator;
    switch(keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
            animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball, "translationX", ball.getX() + STEP_X);
                    animator.start();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball, "translationX", ball.getX() - STEP_X);
            animator.start();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
            animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball, "translationY", ball.getY() - STEP_Y);
            animator.start();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
            animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ball, "translationY",   ball.getY() + STEP_Y);
        animator.start();
        break;
    }
    Rect ballRect = new Rect(ball.getLeft(), ball.getTop(), ball.getRight(), ball.getBottom());
    Rect goalRect = new Rect(goal.getLeft(), goal.getTop(), goal.getRight(), goal.getBottom());

    if(goalRect.intersect(ballRect)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Goal Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Goal Success `Toast` will be displayed upon the intersect

Comment: I'm not sure  this is any different from the code in the question

Comment: mostly similar you just given ball.getBottom() in the goalRect  in the question

Answer (score 0):

You've set the dimensions incorrectly for `goalRect`, change

```
Rect goalRect = new Rect(goal.getLeft(), goal.getTop(), goal.getRight(), ball.getBottom());
```

to

```
Rect goalRect = new Rect(goal.getLeft(), goal.getTop(), goal.getRight(), goal.getBottom());
```

Also, not that this affects your code, but if you use `intersect()`, then `goalRect()` will be set to `ballRect()` if the two Rects intersect. In the future, if you don't want to inadvertently change your Rects, then use `intersects()`. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersect(int,%20int,%20int,%20int) for more info.